# Does Telerik "phone home"? If not, how does it verify that you have paid for it?

Tags: telerik

I'm interested in Telerik (some of the components look really nice), but I am concerned about it phoning home to confirm my subscription.  Does anyone know how this occurs?

My concern is that 1) the phoning home will put extra load on the web server and 2) if Telerik's authentication server goes down for an hour, or a day, then my website could go down too.

Can someone help me to better understand how this works?

Comment: You can definitely talk to Telerik directly to collect the information you need. Besides, consider so many well established companies do use Telerik (and other commercial suites), you know the risks are well managed.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what products do you use, for instance if you have licensed RadControls for ASP.NET Ajax, WPF, etc. then your purchased DLL files are a little different from the Trial dlls and there is no additional validation that occurs at runtime.

Their CMS - Sitefinity, has its own license file which checks if the host (domain) of the request is bound to the license.

Not sure about their backend services though, you better check that with their team.